# Show loading spinner before heavy processing in jQuery Mobile 1.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm going mad trying to get a spinner to appear.  I've bound my heavy processing function to a button thus:

```
$(document).delegate("#clearread", "tap", onClearRead);
```

So on tap it calls this:

```
var onClearRead = function() {

setTimeout($.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg, 5);  

// Civilised cleaning of saved status
var jStorIndex = $.jStorage.index();
for (var i = 0; i < jStorIndex.length; i++) {
    if( jStorIndex[i] != "version" ) {
        $.jStorage.deleteKey(jStorIndex[i]);
    }
}   

// Load articles afresh
loadArticles();

$.mobile.changePage("#choosearticle");

} //onClearRead
```

I find that the spinner **does not appear** during the clearing/loading of articles (about 10 secs) but only for a brief period while the #choosearticle page loads (0.5 secs).
**What am I doing wrong?**

I have the spinner working elsewhere in the app.

Thanks

Comment: @Nirmal Patel just fixed my problem, but anybody know _WHY_ a crazy random settimeout is required?  I've read it's about CPU contention, anybody able to explain in more detail?

Comment: The problem is the JS runs in a single thread in the browser. So if you put in heavy processing; the browser does not attempt to redraw/repaint contents until the JS is finished. And by the time the JS is done; we have invoked a changePage()... the setTimeout just gives the browser enough breather to do other tasks before getting back to heavy lifting in the JS.

Comment: finally, some clarity - thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).delegate("#clearread", "tap", onClearRead);

var onClearRead = function() {
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
setTimeout(function(){  
        //Your heavy processing
        $.mobile.changePage("#choosearticle");
    }, 5);
} //onClearRead
```

Comment: **Yes it works - thank you!**  I have found that you may need to up the milliseconds (to say 100) if the device is slow.  Otherwise the spinner still doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.show( [duration ] [, complete ] )](http://api.jquery.com/show/#show-duration-complete)

Putting the heavy processing in the "complete" function slot, ensures the object (with show called on it) is visible before the show happens.

Related SO Answers

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25207120/999943

[jQuery whole HTML page load with spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742665/jquery-whole-html-page-load-with-spinner)

Example using a CSS based spinner

CSS

```
@-moz-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }

  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(359deg); } }

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg); } }

@-o-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg); }

  100% {
    -o-transform: rotate(359deg); } }

@-ms-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); }

  100% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(359deg); } }

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg); }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(359deg); } }

.icon-spin {
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
  animation: spin 2s infinite linear; }
```

Html using font awesome

```
<div id="spinner" data-bind="visible: isSpinning" style="padding: 10px; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); color: #cccccc; z-index: 1; filter: alpha(opacity=30);">

    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-5x"></i>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('#spinner').show(100, function() {
  // Once the spinner is visible then run the heavy function.
  heavyProcessingFunction();
});
```