# jQuery Mobile where to put showPageLoadingMsg() for click event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to show a loading message when a user clicks a collapsible section while an AJAX get is performed.  I'm using the SPServices library to perform the get.  Basically the loading message does not display.  It will display once the SPServices operation and click event is over.  Am I defining this click event correctly?  Thanks.

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function (event) {
    $('.ui-collapsible').click(function (event, data) {
        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
        var myQueryOptions = "";
        var myQuery = "";
        if ($(this).attr('id') == "NewsContainer" && $("#NewsList li").size() == 0) {
            var myQueryOptions = "<QueryOptions><ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' IncludeRootFolder='True' /></QueryOptions>";
            var myQuery = "<Query><Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId' /><Value Type='ContentTypeId'>0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900DD0126D65DE8404CB540571DFA751B850301</Value></BeginsWith></Where></Query>";
        }
        if (myQueryOptions != "" && myQuery != "") {
            $().SPServices({
                operation: "GetListItems",
                async: false,
                listName: "Pages",
                CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='PublishingPageContent' /><FieldRef Name='NewsDate' /></ViewFields>",
                CAMLQuery: myQuery,
                CAMLRowLimit: 5,
                CAMLQueryOptions: myQueryOptions,
                completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
                        ....
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason to not use jQuery's `$.ajax()` method?

Comment: I'm building this on a SharePoint site and using the SPServices library.  I'm new to the SPServices library, but it exposes a bunch of other powerful functions that SharePoint hides away.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the JS after `showLoading` inside a timeout handler should give you the intended result.

Refer to this question: [Show loading spinner before heavy processing in jQuery Mobile 1.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10923992/190695)